# Read file access/modification timestamp

Tags: c, windows, winapi

What win32 API C functions can I use to read the modification/access/created dates of a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [GetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724320(VS.85).aspx) function. You need to open the file to use this function.

Also, the appropriately named [SetFileTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724933(VS.85).aspx) function will let you modify the times.